# Update table sql query

Tags: sql-server

Soo updating queries are not something I would say I'm great at. My code shows my Original Code, ICD9 Code and ICD10 Code.

Basically I want to take the top 1 of the ICD10 code for each 9 code and update the matching original. The Original will match the ICD9 code.

```
select 
    tf.default_value Orig, 
    MAX(i9.conceptcode) ICD9, 
    MAX(i10.conceptcode) ICD10 
from 
    extract_icd10_9_xref xr
join 
    extract_icd9_concept i9 on i9.concept_id = xr.targetconcept_id
join 
    extract_icd10_concept i10 on i10.concept_id = xr.sourceconcept_id
join 
    template_fields tf on i9.conceptcode = tf.default_value
group by 
    tf.default_value
```

RETURNS (among others)

```
    **ORIG     ICD9     ICD10**
      301.4    301.4    F60.5
      996.2    996.2    T85.199A
      E920.4   E920.4   W27.8xxD
      E918     E918     W23.1xxD
      285.21   285.21   D63.1
      765.10   765.10   P07.10
      593.70   593.70   N13.71
```

Again, I am terrible at update queries. So I am hoping someone could help me write the query for the above so when ran it would overwrite the ORIG in template_fields with the ICD10 in extract_icd10_concept

Very much appreciated for any help on this :/

My terrible first attempt

```
update template_fields tf
set default_value = MAX(i10.conceptcode)
where i9.conceptcode = tf.default_value
join extract_icd9_concept i9 on i9.conceptcode = tf.default_value
join extract_icd10_concept i10 on i10.concept_id = xr.sourceconcept_id
join template_fields tf on i9.conceptcode = tf.default_value
```

Comment: As posted your question doesn't make much sense. There just isn't enough information posted to have a clue what you are trying to do here. I would suggest this as a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: My query above gives the values. I need to take the value in ICD10 and write it to the ORIG column. The ICD9 column is my qualifier to match the 9 with the 10 code. Ive started writing the update but it doesn't look right. Ive modified the original to include what I have so far.

Comment: The only reason I know what you're talking about is because I work in heatlhcare. :) Are you trying to map ICD9 codes to their corresponding ICD10 code? Sounds like you have a 1:many or many:many relationship and just want all of the ICD9s to map to the "top 1" ICD10 that matches. Is that correct?

Comment: rwking - Correct and Correct ;)

Comment: Going to go out on a limb here and assume you are using Nextgen since you have a table name of 'template_fields'. Have you not looked into using the GEM mappings or some other alternative?

Comment: Does it have to be the TOP 1 code? Is that a requirement?

Comment: NG documentation to do this is stating it needs to be done on a 1:1 basis. I do not accept that. With thousands of places to update this is not feasible. I know my current code is close. I just need to get the last couple pieces to line up.

Comment: It doesn't but I would prefer the shortest matching 10 code because the likeness of it being a base code is higher. So I was going to order by char_length(ICD10) and do top 1 that way.

Comment: also GEM mappings convert 10 to 9. I am updating labels and variables etc that have hard coded 9 codes in them. So that wouldn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should update your default_value field with the MAX ICD10 that matches your ICD9.

```
update tf
set tf.default_value = updt.ICD10
from template_fields tf inner join 
     (select i9.conceptcode ICD9, MAX(i10.conceptcode) ICD10
      from extract_icd10_9_xref xr inner join 
           extract_icd9_concept i9 on i9.concept_id = xr.targetconcept_id inner join 
           extract_icd10_concept i10 on i10.concept_id = xr.sourceconcept_id
      group by i9.conceptcode) updt on tf.default_value = updt.ICD9
```

Comment: Thank you much. I was so close to that but I couldn't connect how to get the xref in :/

Comment: You'll get it next time!

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't entirely understand your table structure, it is possible this will need adjustment, but the basic idea is to create a select query to get the ICD10 value. Then join it to the table you want to update (this makes it a derived table). In the query below, you will note that I have a SELECT embedded in a comment. Run this SELECT  instead of the update until you are sure that you are going to be updating correctly.

```
UPDATE tf
SET default_value = a.ICD10
--select tf.default_value, a.ICD10,  *
FROM template_fields tf 
JOIN
  (SELECT tf.default_value Orig, MAX(i10.conceptcode) ICD10 
      FROM extract_icd10_9_xref xr
        JOIN extract_icd9_concept i9 ON i9.concept_id = xr.targetconcept_id
        JOIN extract_icd10_concept i10 ON i10.concept_id = xr.sourceconcept_id
        JOIN template_fields tf ON i9.conceptcode = tf.default_value
      GROUP BY tf.default_value) a 
        ON a.defaultvalue = tf.defaultvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need -

```
  update C
  set C.ORIG = C.ICD10
  --SELECT  C.ORIG,C.ICD9,C.ICD10
  from 
  (
  select xr.ORIG, xr.ICD9, xr.ICD10
  FROM
  (
  select ORIG, ICD9, ICD10
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ICD9 ORDER BY ICD9) Rn
  FROM  extract_icd10_9_xref x
  join extract_icd10_9_xref y
  on x.ORIG = y.ICD9
  ) XR
  where XR.Rn = 1
  )C
```